# Как прибавлять рандомное значение в setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, случайные-числа

Здравствуйте! Есть счетчик и код ниже работает. Сейчас,судя по строке `o.update(v++);` идет прибавление +1 к текущему результату каждую секунду. А можно ли сделать прибавление на рандомный диапазон? Т.е. иногда прибавляет сразу +2,а иногда и +3.

Место где должно быть рандомное число прокомментировал.

```
(function(){
    $('.odometer').each(function(){                         
        var v = 100000;          
        var o = new Odometer({
            el: this,
            value: v,
            format:'',
            theme: $(this).data('theme')
        });
        o.render();
        setInterval(function(){                
            o.update(v++); // ВОТ ТУТ ДОЛЖНО БЫТЬ РАНДОМНОЕ ЧИСЛО
        }, 1000); 
    });
})();
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Math.random() вернет число от 0 до 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого обычно пользуются функцией [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

```js
// Рандомное целое от 1 до 10
console.log(Math.floor(1+10*Math.random()));
```

```
(function(){
    $('.odometer').each(function(){                         
        var v = 100000;          
        var o = new Odometer({
            el: this,
            value: v,
            format:'',
            theme: $(this).data('theme')
        });
        o.render();
        setInterval(function(){
            v = v + Math.floor(1+10*Math.random()); 
            o.update(v);
        }, 1000); 
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getRandomInt(min, max)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, делайте по возможности более развёрнутые ответы.